# React - Latitude and Longitude state incorrect when using `useEffect`

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have previously asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68674540/react-latitude-and-longitude-state-incorrect-when-used-in-openweathermap-api-c) and implemented some changes relating to the article linked. However, I am still confused about how exactly to get what I need. I'm still new to React and don't have much experience with `useEffect` so I would like to know the correct way of doing things.

The initial problem was that I set the state of latitude and longitude through coordinates from the city search data object. When I `console.log` the values, they appear correct, but when I use them in the One Call API, it does not work as expected - it `console.logs` as

> cod: "400" message: "wrong latitude"

or

> cod: "400" message: "Nothing to geocode"

This still occurs even after I've added the `useEffect`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Another related question, I used `onClick` to trigger the API call with functions, but you are not able to access the functions inside of a `useEffect`. How can I trigger the API call so the data is also rendered on the page like it was without the `useEffect`? I have seen examples of this, but in each of them, the state is set to an array or object (e.g. `const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([])`). The state for the lat and long are just numbers so I did not set them to an object or array. Could this be related to the initial problem? Thanks in advance.

Updated code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Weather from "./Weather";

export default function Form(props) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [lat, setLat] = useState();
  const [lon, setLon] = useState();
  const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([]);

  //search for weather through city name
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getWeatherData() {
      //this one has access to lat and long

      const data = await fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${input}&cnt=7&appid=38f1fbc74deb031d79636062ba66d984`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          //set states to include weather detail, and current longitude and latitude
          setLat(data.city.coord.lat);
          setLon(data.city.coord.lon);
          const weatherInfo = [...new Set(data.list.map((item) => item))];
          setForecast(weatherInfo);
        });
 
    }
  });

  console.log("latitude -----", lat);
  console.log("longitude -----", lon);

  //search for weather with zip code
  async function getWeatherDataZip(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = await fetch(
      `  https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${input}&appid={APIKEY}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data);

    console.log("zipzip", data);
  }

  //get precipitation info from one call API
  async function getPrecipitationData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = await fetch(
      `  https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&exclude=hourly&appid={APIKEY}`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => data);

    console.log("LATLON DATA", data);
  }

  //display weather details
  function displayWeather() {
    const currentTemp = [
      ...new Set(
        forecast.map((item, index) => (
          <Weather
            item={item.main}
            desc={item.weather}
            wind={item.wind}
            key={index}
          />
        ))
      ),
    ];
    return currentTemp;
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  function handleChange(e) {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="input-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form"
            placeholder="Enter a city name..."
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={(e) => {
            // getWeatherData(e);
            getWeatherDataZip(e);
            getPrecipitationData(e);
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
      <div className="weather">
        <span>{displayWeather()}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a useEffect function like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => { 
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${input}&cnt=7&appid=38f1fbc74deb031d79636062ba66d984`
      );
      const data = await res.json();
      //set states to include weather detail, and current longitude and latitude
      setLat(data.city.coord.lat);
      setLon(data.city.coord.lon);
      const weatherInfo = [...new Set(data.list.map((item) => item))];
      setForecast(weatherInfo);
    })();
  }, [input]);
```

Note the `[input]` at the end. It ensures that the useEffect only gets called when input changes.

Your current code won't do anything when useEffect is called because all you do there is declare a function, rather than actually running it.

EDIT: We need to wrap the async function in useEffect function so it does not return a promise: React does not like that since the return value of a useEffect function has to be nothing OR a clean-up function.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would I have to include `async` anywhere here? I got an error for that part

Comment: ah yes! Edited.

Comment: I have tried your answer and found that as I try to access an object deeper, the data is undefined. For instance, `data.city` appears in the console.log, but `data.city.coord` is undefined. Do you have any suggestions for this? Thank you!

Comment: For example, if i search for London in the app, this will appear if I console.log(data.city):

 ```"city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 51.5085,
      "lon": -0.1257
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 1000000,
    "timezone": 3600,
    "sunrise": 1628224321,
    "sunset": 1628278845
  }```

 but when I console.log data.city.coord, the result is undefined, so I'm not able to access anything inside of it

Comment: Sorry, but that really makes no sense. You are making a mistake somewhere. If that's what data.city show, then data.city.coord is *not* undefined. Please check what you're doing carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your useEffect to something like this.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      await fetch(
          `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${input}&cnt=7&appid=38f1fbc74deb031d79636062ba66d984`
        )
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            //set states to include weather detail, and current longitude and latitude
            setLat(data.city.coord.lat);
            setLon(data.city.coord.lon);
            const weatherInfo = [...new Set(data.list.map((item) => item))];
            setForecast(weatherInfo);
          });
    })()
  }, [input]);
```