# Chaining three different async functions

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, promise

I have three async functions but the third function is running before the second one resolves. What is wrong here?

```
 async function getSet () {
//get settings from asyncstorage and setstate
}

 async function pairs () {
//fetch data and set another state
}

 async function fetchIt () {
//fetch another data and set a third state
}
useEffect(() => {
    getSet()
      .then(pairs())
      .then(fetchIt())
      .then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```

fetchIt() is running before pairs()

Comment: I have corrected the code because I don't need their results. I want only to set the state.

Comment: i've corrected my question actually :)

Comment: [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15886272) | [Confusion with how thenable callback works in Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59878462)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a function call and function reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886272/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-call-and-function-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calls aren't chained properly. To make it simpler use `async await`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function () {
      await getSet();
      await pairs();
      await fetchIt();
      setLoading(false);
    })();
  }, []);
```

If each call depends on the result of the last it looks like

```
const r1 = await getSet();
const r2 = await pairs(r1);
// etcetera
```

Comment: getting an error "An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up"

Comment: To explain - React is checking what the useEffect function returns, as the returned value can be a clean up function. However an async function always returns a promise, so we need to wrap it in another function to stop the promise being returned. 

Comment: No @jfriend00 you can't. That's what I started with but had to modify it because I forgot that nicety of React.

Comment: Please see comments above no. 2 and 4.

Comment: OK, that's really inconvenient of React.  Must have been designed before `async`.

Comment: @Bravo a fair point - I might not have suggested it if I'd remembered this detail about React useEffect.

Comment: @Bravo - The whole point of using `async/await` is that it's a LOT cleaner to sequence multiple asynchronous operations.  In this case, you have to put in a AIIFE to get around React's objection to returning a promise, but IMO, that's worth it for cleaner sequencing of multiple asynchronous operations.  Chaining a bunch of `.then()` is certainly doable, but not as clean IMO.

Comment: It's clearly just a matter of preference. For consistency's sake I *always* use async await where I can.

Comment: @Bravo I don't think async await is cool and new. I think it is simple to read and understand. And the fact that this question exists shows how easy it is to get the .then chaining wrong. But I have no interest in telling you when you *should* use it. Kindly do me the same favour.

Comment: @Bravo I think you might have overreacted a little. Enjoy the sandpit.

Comment: yeah, sure I did, that's why I deleted the comments. Because, apparently, expressing my opinion in response to an opinion is telling you what to do. yeah, I over reacted.

Comment: FYI - you may want to correct yourself here https://stackoverflow.com/a/68675196/10549313 - wonder why that code doesn't have the same problem this code had before you fixed your error (I thought I'd seen you answer somewhere else recently)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I remembered I made the same mistake recently but wasn't sure where.

Answer (score -3):

You haven't chained the 'then's properly. They must return a promise as well. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```js
const getSet = async() => {
  //get settings from asyncstorage and setstate
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('getSet');
  });
}

const pairs = async() => {
  //fetch data and set another state
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('pairs');
  });
}

const fetchIt = async() => {
  //fetch another data and set a third state
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('fetchIt');
  });
}

getSet()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return pairs();
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    return fetchIt();
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    // setLoading(false);
  });
```

Comment: while your code is technically correcter than the OP - your explanation is wrong - `.then` always return a Promise, and you don't need to return a promise inside a .then callback ... so thumbs up for correcter code (not the best, solution to be honest), but work on the explanation

Comment: Ah right, thanks for pointing that out. Perhaps it can act as an example of how NOT to chain promises. ;)